# JBoss EAP 6.4 to 7.1 migration Issue SOAP

Tags: soap, jboss, soapui, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

We are getting the below response when trying to hit SOAP web service from SOAP UI after deploying in EAP 7.1 with necessary changes in standalone XML. The same works fine in JBoss EAP 6.4 version

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EAP JBoss 7 introduced undertow as web server and servlet container.
There were some changed introduced with it, particularly regarding POST for .html pages, which I think it's your case.

### Workaround

Compiling your project as JSP to be deployed as servlet container, perhaps.

### Obs

Please post the server.log and configuration files (in case it's not vanilla installation).